# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/p]

Tags: java, spring, xsd, schema

I am trying to run 'Hello World' example from *Pro Spring 5, 5th edition* book. I build project with `maven`. Build is ok But when I run it with `java -jar HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` it shows:

```sh
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/p]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/app-context.xml]
...
```

**app-context.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="provider" class="com.example.HelloWorldMessageProvider"/>
    <bean id="renderer" class="com.example.StandardOutMessageRenderer" p:messageProvider-ref="provider"/>
</beans>
```

**HelloWorld.java**

```java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/app-context.xml");
        MessageRenderer mr = ctx.getBean("renderer", MessageRenderer.class);
        mr.render();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.example.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Problem disappears if I use `spring-boot` instead of pure spring. I have found similar problems on stackoverflow, but they are about missing dependencies. I think my dependencies are OK. So what is a problem?